# Configuring Template::Toolkit in Dancer2's config.yml (trimming whitespace)

Tags: perl, template-engine, dancer

I'm using Dancer2 to build a web application. It works great but when I *view source* in the browser, the generated HTML source code is full of scattered whitespace, like so

```
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>



            <td>Cheeseburger</td>

        <td>4.50&nbsp;€</td>
    </tr>
```

My templates had `<% ... %>` code at the places where now the whitespace is. I'd prefer if it looked like this:

```
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
            <td>Cheeseburger</td>
        <td>4.50&nbsp;€</td>
    </tr>
```

or, even better:

```
<tr><td>2</td><td>Cheeseburger</td><td>4.50&nbsp;€</td></tr>
```

I'm using Template::Toolkit and thought the `TRIM` attribute is exactly what I need and added it to my `config.yml`:

```
template: "template_toolkit"
session: "YAML"

engines:
  session:
    YAML:
      cookie_duration: 6 months
  template:
    template_toolkit:
      start_tag: '<%'
      end_tag:   '%>'
      TRIM:      '1'
```

But this doesn't work. I already changed `start_tag` and `end_tag` to something different (to verify this file is read) and that actually worked. But the `TRIM` option does not.

Am I using the wrong option or giving it at the wrong place? All the googling I did showed how to set TT-options programmatically as e.g. in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4187782/5830574). But as I do not explicitely instantiate anything TT related, I don't even know where I should put such code.

---

I created my app with `dancer2 -a so`.

**views/index.tt**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <% FOREACH item in group.items %>
            <tr>
                <td><% item.order_num %></td>
                <%# one-line comment %>
                <%# one-line comment %>
                <%# one-line comment %>
                    <td><% item.desc %></td>
                <%# one-line comment %>
                <td><% currency(item.price) %></td>
            </tr>
        <% END %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`group.items` is an array of hashrefs; `currency` is a function to format the price. The `<%# one-line comment %>` are my old code (I'm migrating from [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) to Dancer2).

**lib/so.pm** (the app's module)

```
package so;
use Dancer2;

our $VERSION = '0.1';

get '/' => sub {

    my $group = {
        items => [
            {
                order_num => 1,
                desc => 'Hamburger',
                price => 350,
            },
            {
                order_num => 2,
                desc => 'Cheeseburger',
                price => 450,
            },
        ]
    };

    template 'index', {
        group => $group,
        currency => sub { sprintf('%.2f&nbsp;€', $_[0]/100); },
    };
};

true;
```

Comment: Please show the snip of the template that coincides with your example here so we can test.

Comment: @stevieb I just amended my post.

Comment: You can also ignore whitespace from individual blocks by putting a `-` there. `<%-` and `-%>` respectively. Be careful if you use this in JS code, you might shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @simbabque I'll try those in the next step. But thank you for pointing me to Dancer2 at all. It's just awesome :-) compared to CGI. Like Assembler vs. some high level language.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that. Have you figured out the deployment yet? It's a bit different than CGI (unless you use CGI, but that would not be the smartest move).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're enabling `TRIM` correctly in your config file, but `TRIM` only removes whitespace from the very beginning and the very end of a block or template file. To remove whitespace from the middle of a template file, use [`PRE_CHOMP`/`POST_CHOMP`](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Config.html#section_PRE_CHOMP_POST_CHOMP):

> Anything outside a directive tag is considered plain text and is generally passed through unaltered...This includes all whitespace and newlines characters surrounding directive tags. Directives that don't generate any output will leave gaps in the output document.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Foo
> [% a = 10 %]
> Bar
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> Foo
>
> Bar
> ```
>
> The PRE_CHOMP and POST_CHOMP options can help to clean up some of this extraneous whitespace. Both are disabled by default.

There are several possible settings for `PRE_CHOMP` and `POST_CHOMP` that affect how much whitespace is stripped; none of them generates really pretty output, so you'll have to play around and decide which you like best.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that I set TRIM correctly in config.yml. That helped a lot. I played a bit with PRE/POST_CHOMP and indeed it gives better (yet not perfect) results. I misunderstood TRIM and thought it is similar to _"PRE and POST_CHOMP to the max"_.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility to get rid of superfluous whitespace is the `collapse` filter<sup>[1](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Manual/Filters.pod#collapse), [2](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Filters.html#section_collapse)</sup>
of Template::Toolkit. It collapses all consecutive whitespace (including newlines) to a single space character:

From the docs:

> ```
> [% FILTER collapse %]
>
>    The   cat
>
>    sat    on
>
>    the   mat
>
> [% END %]
> ```
>
> **Output:**
>
> ```
> The cat sat on the mat
> ```

My `views/layouts/main.tt` contains a line

```
<% content %>
```

If I replace that with

```
<% content FILTER collapse %>
```

then the resulting body of the HTML page is one single (and very long) line.

**Attention:** this will break any `<pre>` and `<code>` blocks (and perhaps some more).